# TortoiseSVN update/cleanup error between Linux repository and Windows XP

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows

For no reason that I can see, I can no longer run a TortoiseSVN Update on a development directory on my portable Windows XP Professional SP3 machine, getting the error:

> Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
>   Please execute the 'Cleanup' command.

If I try running cleanup, I get another error,

> cannot process the following paths: cannot move $ROOT_DIR/.svn/tmp/tmp-... to $ROOT_DIR/path/where/thing/should/go: no such file or directory

I have verified that both files exist, and actually from CMD.EXE prompt I am able to issue a MOVE with those two filenames and have it work correctly. It's no use because next time SVN tries to repeat the operation itself after creating a different `tmp` file name, and while CMD succeeded, SVN fails.

**UPDATE**: the path lengths are in both cases well below PATH_MAX, target file system is NTFS, and permissions are OK. Maybe I'll now try with [FileMon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor#FileMon) to see whatever TortoiseSVN is really up to.

I tried downgrading TortoiseSVN but to no avail. Other repositories work OK between the same machines.

```
TortoiseSVN 1.7.9, Build 23248 - 32 Bit , 2012/08/30 18:25:37
Subversion 1.7.6, 
apr 1.4.6
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
zlib 1.2.7
```

Both server (OpenSuSE Linux 12.2) and client now run the latest version of SVN.

On Windows, I also cannot seem to get any more informative logs or information (I'm not very skilled with TortoiseSVN, I have always used the Linux command line version).

I might delete the local copy and run a checkout, but it's about 2 GB of data, and I'm on a slow connection, so it is really more of a "fly physically to server location and hook a copper Ethernet to the local network there" alternative. I'm reserving that as a sort of last ditch, nuclear option; I'd really rather understand what the problem is, for I fear it might happen again.

**UPDATE**

I've tried to delete remotely the subdirectory involved, committing the deletion on the server; deleting the subdirectory locally, and emptying the `.svn/tmp` subdirectory where I found sixteen `tmp` files, all copies of the one PNG causing problems.

I am still not able to perform any SVN subcommand, getting "Run cleanup!" error; on cleanup; I get a failed attempt to copy a tmpfile to the never-sufficiently-damned .PNG file, which no longer exists anywhere, into a directory that no longer exists anywhere.

I tried recreating the directory locally (but not the file!), no changes.

With FileMon, I traced  the source PNG to `8e4c2389cf9d85c8b8ee54d49ea053c752a38187.svn-base` in .svn/pristine subdirectory, tried removing it and got SVN complaining. I tried copying it to its intended destination (so that the file-as-it-should-be and the file-as-it-is are identical), no joy.

**UPDATE**

Well, this is weird. I decided to track *everything* that TortoiseSVN is doing using FileMon. I could see it checking the `wc.db` and search the item, checking for it in `.svn/pristine` (and finding it), copying it (unnecessarily if you ask me...) in `.svn/tmp`, and finally checking `$DESTINATION_FILE` (with correct case) using Windows Open() API. And getting PATH NOT FOUND. Yet the file *is* there, I can see it (and the name is less than 8.3 characters). And why **PATH** not found and not **FILE** not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it all boiled down to a directory that had been created remotely with a name ending with *space*. The file in itself was OK; the directory where it stood was *not*.

When updating, apparently, the directory got created but the name was shortened by Windows to exclude the final space.

To add to the difficulty of diagnosing, while TortoiseSVN *did* tell me what the problem was, it did so in the dialog box where the Arial font made the space in `\path\to\your \file` not clearly recognizable (it was, once I knew where to look, and compared that slash with the others. This one stood a little farther from the letter at its left).

Lesson learned: check really carefully the dialog file name, character by character (note to self: find a way of having it in Courier New if at all possible).

Answer (score 1):

You may have two files in the repository that differ only in case. That's a problem on Windows. See this [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#cantmove) for details.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but it's not the reason - I've emptied my local directory with no joy. I'll now try running a SVN DELETE after copying the three files it contains; it's a small enough operation not to matter.